# Cruise Control Build report formatting

Tags: configuration, formatting, report, cruisecontrol

I have already setup Cruise Control build server and it is working fine.
It's just that in the build report it shows warnings with "red" color which are actually meaningless for my project.

Is there a way I could configure the report generation logic and format the color of warnings to "grey", or any other than "red". It will actually be more intuitive for the users of build report.

Please suggest.

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the issue. I could achieve this by modifying Cruise Control style sheet for warning.

Comment: Please share the solution for future visitors.